# How to open XML from TMemoryStream at TWebBrowser?

Tags: xml, delphi, memorystream, twebbrowser

I would like to open TMemoryStream which contains XML raw data at my TWebBrowser component?
How I can achieve this?

Comment: Try this http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=14.

Comment: It's not working for me. I've used "InternalLoadDocumentFromStream" procedure from that article and it gives me an Access Violation on:
if PersistStreamInit.InitNew = S_OK then

Comment: That's what I don't want to believe. That would mean the `QueryInterface` method fails in its job.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I used it in right way. I am creating TmemoryStream object inside my TThread class, when thread finished his job I'm passing memorystream to my global variable, and assigning my global variable as a return of my tthread function. Next, I'm calling my tthread function from main form and getting memory stream inside my main form (its size tells me that everything is ok) by assigning function to memorystream variable created inside my main form. Then I'm checking if memstream in my mainform is assigned (it is) and then calling procedure to load stream. And it gives me an error.

Comment: Getting access violation on that line would mean the `QueryInterface` call returns `S_OK` but doesn't return a valid `IPersistStreamInit` interface reference. That would be critical error and the world would cease to make sense :) Are you absolutely sure it fails on that line ?

Comment: When I'm debugging this code and my debugger stops there, and I press F8 it gives me an AV.

Comment: Did you read the text below `InternalLoadDocumentFromStream` that discusses the *type of stream* that is needed (the third and fourth paragraphs of text below the code block)? It's highly unlikely that the code from that article just *doesn't work*, as it's been around for quite some time. Chances are much greater that you've just not used it properly because you didn't read the article but just tried to use it and did so incorrectly as a result.